# Many to many relationship alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I have a user model, and a tasks model.

Task:

```
class Task < Sequel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Serialization
  many_to_one :subject, polymorphic: true
  many_to_one :creator, key: :created_by, class: :User

  def_dataset_method(:sort_recent) do
    order(Sequel.desc(:created_at), Sequel.desc(:id))
  end

end
```

User:

```
class User < Sequel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Serialization

  one_to_many :task
end
```

Now I want the user to be able to create and assign a task to multiple other users, but I am puzzled what is the best way to do that (I guess through a join table) and if I need another model or not.

Comment: `TaskUser` would probably be the most obvious.

Comment: @JoshBrody user is both the creator, and another user can also be the one to which the task is assigned to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sequel `many_to_many` creates  [many to many associations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))  without a model (but with a join table of course). This is the equivalent to `has_and_belongs_to_many` in ActiveRecord.

```
DB.create_table :assignments do
  primary_key :id
  foreign_key(:user_id)
  foreign_key(:task_id)
end

class Task
  many_to_many :assigned_users, 
    class: :User, 
    join_table: :assignments,
    right_key: :user_id # this might not be needed
end

class User
  many_to_many :assigned_tasks, 
    class: :Task,
    join_table: :assignments,
    right_key: :task_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd most likely want an associations table like `task_users` containing columns `user_id` and `task_id`. This allows `Task` to have a `has_many :assignees, through: :task_users` association. The inverse association for `User` can be implemented as well.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: This is a Sequel question - not ActiveRecord.